# Override ShippingMethodMangement.php

Tags: magento2

I need to override this model but

`<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodMangement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />`

in di.xml is not working

the method I need to override is `public function apply($cartId, $carrierCode, $methodCode)`

any help please

Answer (score 1):

You have typo error in `preference` definition

`Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodMangement` <- incorrect (missed **a**)

`Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement` <- correct

**Better way to overwrite is set preference to related interfaces**

```xml
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface"
            type="Vendor\Module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Api\ShipmentEstimationInterface"
            type="Vendor\Module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface"
            type="Vendor\Module\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" />
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, working fine now you've pointed that out. Feel like a bit of an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use plugin as below (Hide another shipping if freeshipping is available).

let’s create “di.xml” file at the given below path,
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc

```
 <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
        <plugin name="shipping_method_management" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

Step 2: Now, the last step is to create a “ShippingMethodManagement.php” file at the give below path,
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Model;

class ShippingMethodManagement {

    public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
    {
        return $this->filterOutput($output);
    }
    private function filterOutput($output)
    {
        $free = [];
        foreach ($output as $shippingMethod) {
            if ($shippingMethod->getCarrierCode() == 'freeshipping' && $shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == 'freeshipping') {
                $free[] = $shippingMethod;
            }
        }
        if ($free) {
            return $free;
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Note: above code is for **Hide another shipping if freeshipping is available.**